# Did the Sefer Torah written by the Maharam of Rottenberg survive the Holocaust?

Tags: history, rishonim, holocaust-shoah, sefer-torah

There is a famous story of the Maharam copying a Sefer Torah written by Moshe Rabbeinu. Before passing, he threw it in the river by the castle in which he was arrested.

This Sefer Torah reached Worms, and was held in their shul. The Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe said that he saw it in 1907 (See [Hayom Yom for the 7th of Elul](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5906/jewish/Elul-7.htm)). Does anyone know if it survived the Holocaust?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per this link http://www.torahlab.org/calendar/article/is_there_another_torah/

> Today the Maharam’s Torah is in the Aron Kodesh of the famous Alt-neu
>   shul in Prague.